# What forces are applied to the wall when some thing like a cooler is attached to it? what makes the normal force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

what force throw to the wall is applied in this situation?

[image]

what force does this wood is importing to the wall that makes the normal force?

Answer (score 1):

A normal reaction force by the wall is needed to prevent rotation of the bracket assembly.

The top diagram below shows the bracket secured to the wall. For simplicity, the wall and bracket don't contact one another along the surface (a small gap between) and are bolted together at the two locations shown. These two locations support the bracket.

The bottom diagram shows a free body diagram of the bracket. To simplify things, the point labeled COM is assumed to be the center of mass of the entire bracket assembly plus any load on the shelf. The forces the wall exert on the bracket are at the two support points are shown. The corresponding reaction forces at the wall are also shown. Equilibrium requirements are that the sum of the forces in the vertical and horizontal direction need to be zero, and the sum of the moments (torques) about anywhere on the bracket needs to be zero. The sum of the moments about the center of mass of the bracket is chosen in this example. The equations are shown.

The horizontal normal force $R2_{HW}$ at the wall is needed to provide a clockwise moment about the COM to oppose the counter-clockwise moments due to $R1_{VW}$ and $R2_{VW}$ about the COM. The horizontal reaction force $R1_{HW}$ is needed to counter the horizontal reaction force $R2_{HW}$ so that the sum of the horizontal forces is zero.

> I really appreciate this, thank you. but can you explain this a little
>   bit easier that a student like me who's 16 years old understands this?

Ok, try and get a feeling for what the stresses will be on the wall where the bracket is secured, if a heavy weight is placed on the shelf. Can you sense that the weight will have a tendency to try and pull the top fastener out of the wall? That's the force $R1_{HW}$ the bracket exerts on the wall. At the same time the wall will tend to pull on bracket preventing it from separating from the wall. Thats the force $R1_{HW}$ the wall exerts on the bracket. These forces that are needed to prevent the bracket from pulling away from the wall at the top and rotating about the center of mass are the cause of the normal forces on the wall.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Amin I need to know what you know about statics. Do you know that torque (moment) tends to cause an object to rotate or twist?

Comment: @Amin OK, I've added some text to try and give you an intuitive feel for what is going on. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks man. but a question, I read it all, and the question now for me is this that is the normal force equal to the weight of the bracket?

Comment: @Amin No. The normal forces are perpendicular to the wall, $R1_{HW}$ and $R2_{HW}$. They are due to the moment (torque) created by the weight that pulls the bracket away from the wall at the top and presses the bracket at the bottom. The sum of the vertical reaction forces $R1_{VW}$ and $R2_{VW}$ equals the weight.